# Issue Target[Interface] repository is not instantiable while building in laravel8

Tags: laravel-8

I'm working with Laravel 9 and I have a Controller like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\RegisterUser;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace;
use App\Models\Category;

class CustomRegisterController extends Controller
{
    private $registerUserRepository;

    public function __construct(UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace $registerUserRepository)
    {
        $this->registerUserRepository = $registerUserRepository;
    }

    public function registerUser(RegisterUser $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        $this->registerUserRepository->storeUser($data);
        dd($data);
    }
}
```

And here is the UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace:

```
<?php
namespace App\Repositories\Interfaces;

Interface UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace{
    public function storeUser($data);
}
?>
```

And this is the UserRegisterRepository itself:

```
<?php
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace;
use App\Models\User;

class UserRegisterRepository implements UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace{
    public function storeUser($data){
        return User::create($data);
    }
}

?>
```

Here is the appserviceprovider.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRegisterRepositoryInterface;
use App\Repositories\UserRegisterRepository;

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind(UserRegisterRepositoryInterface::class, UserRegisterRepository::class);
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }
}
```

But now I get this error:

Target [App\Repositories\Interfaces\UserRegisterRepositoryInterFace] is not instantiable while building [App\Http\Controllers\CustomRegisterController].

So what's going wrong here?

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Laravel 8 or Laravel 9?

Comment: @brombeer Laravel Framework 8